# Sort list of tuples based on month

Tags: python

I have something like this

```py
print(x)
 >>> [('01/01-01/03', 4), ('01/06-01/10', 5), ('01/13-01/17', 4), ('01/20-01/24', 5), ('01/27-01/31', 5), ('02/03-02/07', 5) ... ]
```

for a whole year.

It contains a `str` of days in week and number of working days (5 - holidays). I would like to sort this `list` of `tuples` to start with July (7th month).

So something like this

```
x.sort(first occurrence of `07/` in str of index 0 of tuples in list)
```

Comment: What does "to sort to start with July" mean exactly? What happens with, for example, January?

Comment: July --> August --> September --> October --> November --> December --> January  .... (till June)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
data = [('01/01-01/03', 4), ('01/06-01/10', 5), ('01/13-01/17', 4), ('01/20-01/24', 5), ('01/27-01/31', 5), ('02/03-02/07', 5),
        ('07/20-07/24', 5), ('07/27-07/31', 5), ('08/03-08/07', 5)]

def sort_key(t):
    m = re.match(r"(\d\d)/(\d\d)-\d\d/\d\d", t[0])
    month = int(m.group(1))
    day = int(m.group(2))
    if month < 7:
        month += 12
    return month * 100 + day

data_sorted = sorted(data, key=sort_key)

print(data_sorted)
```

Result:

```
[('07/20-07/24', 5), ('07/27-07/31', 5), ('08/03-08/07', 5), ('01/01-01/03', 4), ('01/06-01/10', 5), ('01/13-01/17', 4), ('01/20-01/24', 5), ('01/27-01/31', 5), ('02/03-02/07', 5)]
```